# Verification Failed. There was an error in connecting to your Apple ID

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id

I have an iPhone 5c and I've been trying to log onto my iTunes and Apple Store in my settings, but I keep getting a *"Verification Failed. There was an error in connecting to your Apple ID."* error. I don't know how to do resolve this. When I go onto my iCloud on my iPhone it says that my email is not verified even though I went to my email and verified it, it isn't recognized as verified on my iPhone.

Answer (score 33):

This was driving me crazy! Accidentally the "set time/date automatically" had been turned off and the date was way off. Turning this back on made everything work again! Apple ID worked and all Google apps (YouTube) started working again.

Comment: I can confirm, that this was the solution on my IPad as well.

Comment: me too, weird thing was it was also stopping me go to Google.com, the certificate was not valid but other https sites did work.

Comment: My date/time settings were set to automatically update, but toggling this setting off and then back on made it work! Cheers!

Comment: Wiping an old 5C to give to someone and had the same error.  And the same solution.  I also had to toggle, as the auto date/time was set.  For January...which is around when I got a new phone (it's September now).

Comment: Worked on Iphone SE

Comment: Really old Ipad and spent hours troubleshooting this. I had made Date Time automatic but it was so far off that I didn't notice it wasn't updating it. Once I manually changed date to today worked perfectly! Was about to go to Apple Store.

Answer (score 18):

This could be caused by a number of scenarios. One of the most common things to check is whether you're actually connected to the internet (preferably WiFi)? I have seen many people not realise they weren't connected, especially after an iOS update.

In addition, two of the most common things to try are:

- Doing a full reboot of your iPhone (i.e. holding down the Power and Home buttons simulatenousy for about 10 secs until you see the Apple logo on a black screen)
- Logging out and back in. (See steps below)

You don't actually clarify what version of iOS you're running, but here are some generic steps to take:

1. Go to Settings >iTunes & App Store
2. Tap on your Apple ID at the very top
3. Tap on Sign Out
4. Now sign back in

Hope this helps. Let us know you go, as there are other possible ways to fix this.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. I only required the full reboot step in this case. It had been driving me crazy.

Comment: Reboot didn't work for me but resigning in did, thanks!

Comment: In my case I was trying to turn off Find iPhone so I could wipe a phone. That produced the verification failed error. Signing out of iTunes didn't help. HOWEVER, signing out of iCloud, rather than turning off Find iPhone, did work. Then I could reset the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. connect via wifi
2. go to `Settings > iCloud`
3. click on your account
4. generate a verification code from another Apple device which uses the same Apple ID, by going to (the other Apple device and click) `Settings > iCloud > Password and Security > Generate verification code`
5. enter the verification code in the device with the error

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I realized the time and date on my phone were wrong.  Once I updated the time and date correctly all verification worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you had previously installed OPENDNS/Cisco Umbrella Disable it and reinstall it.  After a restore and upgrade the VPN Client was unable to connect and was not allowing the User to connect to iCloud or the verification servers.

Comment: YES!  This was my issue.  I turned off Wifi and used my cellular data and it worked.  THANKS!