# Stuck in a Bad iCloud Session

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I dropped my new iPhone into the Puget Sound, so I'm trying to use my old iPhone for now. I have a new SIM card installed, but I seem to be stuck in an iCloud loop.

In order to do pretty much anything on my phone, I have to be signed into iCloud. When I try to sign in, I get this error: `Verification Failed: There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server.`

According to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255585/verification-failed-there-was-an-error-in-connecting-to-your-apple-id), the solution seems to be to sign out and sign back in again. However, I can't sign out without turning off "Find My iPhone", which asks for a password and gives me an error.

I also tried resetting my phone, both through the settings menu and through iTunes, but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The network settings needed to be reset, which I did by going to `Settings > General > Reset` and clicking on `Reset Network Settings`.